# Use mod_rewrite to simulate Facebook style URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want the address bar to show:

```
http://facebook.com/user

http://facebook.com/user/ -> http://facebook.com/user

http://facebook.com/user/photos -> http://facebook.com/user/photos
```

My rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)$ user.php?id=$1&second=$2 [NC,L]
```

What happens:

```
1). http://domain.com/user (working well)

2). http://domain.com/user/ (keeps the / in the address bar and destroys css/js/img paths)

3). http://domain.com/user/photos (same result as 2, correct except the paths)
```

If I use `<base href="...">` to force the paths the page displays correctly. But I want to solve my problem without it.

How can I remove the trailing slash in the address bar? The rewriting seem to be working like intended.

Comment: I am not sure what "facebook style URLs" really mean for you, but what you show looks like regular "friendly urls". Just google for that

Comment: did you tried `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,NC]` ?

Comment: Lovely with downvotes on a well formulated question.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com What I mean is that when you enter for example facebook.com/user/ they somehow remove the trailing slash. I am not able to reproduce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going to use Friendly URLs, you must use absolute paths for your resources.

#### Initial Declaration

You might have declared `index.php` with this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />
<img src="assets/user.png" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/home.js"></script>
```

#### Proposed Way using `/` for Absolute Paths

But it has to be translated this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css" />
<img src="/assets/user.png" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/home.js"></script>
```

Notice the `/` in the front to make them as Absolute URLs.

#### Using `<base href="/" />`

If this is going to be a tedious task for you, you can use this tag:

```
<base href="/" />
```

This will make your Relative URLs to relate with the Root.

#### Using a `$baseurl` variable

Another better way is to prepend with a `$baseurl` variable.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/stylesheets/styles.css" />
<img src="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/assets/user.png" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/scripts/home.js"></script>
```

This way, you can even change the `$baseurl` value if you are hosting in a folder and not in the root!

Comment: Yes I started building a $base variable, but got annoyed when I had to send it into functions. I guess I'll have to do it this way and include some general settings-file with $base. Thanks!

Comment: I often change folders between a development environment and the production environment. I guess I'll just have to remember to change the settings file :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you someone access `http://domain.com/user/photos` for example, the css, js and other relative links in the page resolves to `http://domain.com/user/css/main.css` (for example).

You have two solutions for this :

- Add base tag in head section of the page (wich you tried already)
- Change all relative links in your page absolute links (wich I don't recommand you)

So the easier solution is to use the base tag.

Note: Even if you remove the slash in the end, it may work for `http://domain.com/user/` but will definitly not work for `http://domain.com/user/photos`